# How to remove or hide the data value not required from table in birt tool

Tags: filter, birt

How do I remove or hide the data value not required from table in **birt tool**?

I tried with the values it works in some places but now in groups which has multiple values.

I need to filter some of the values which should not be displayed in the data tab of the table.

I have a column which does not have any value that I need to filter out (But its not an empty value because when I check I got to know that it has some blank spaces). It should display only the columns with *non-blank* value.

How can I remove those columns from the data set.

Comment: Please specify your requirement clearly. Also put some code what you have tried. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course try scripting the data source query but you can also run a script on the table when it is created to hide the empty column.

Try this script in the table's onCreate event:

```
var mycolumnCount = this.getRowData().getColumnCount();
var DisNull = false;

for(i=1;i<mycolumnCount;i++) {

var temp = this.getRowData().getColumnValue(i)
    if(this.getRowData().getColumnValue(i) == "") {
    DisNull = true;
    }else{
        DisNull = false;
        i = mycolumnCount+1;
        }
    }

if(DisNull == true) {
this.getStyle().display = "none"
}
```